# If I have two sums $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i = N$ and $\sum_{i=1}^N b_i = N$, how to show $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i b_i \geq N$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assume we have $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $N$ positive real numbers $a_1,\dots,a_N$ and $b_1,\dots,b_N$ with  $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i = N$ and $\sum_{i=1}^N b_i = N$. How can I show that  $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i b_i \geq N$?

I tried to set $b_i = a_i + \delta_i$ with $\sum_{i=1}^N \delta_i = 0$ to arrive at $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i b_i = \sum_{i=1}^N (a_i^2 + a_i \delta_i)$. I found that $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i^2 \geq N$, but I am stuck with how to handle the second part of the sum.

Comment: You cannot show it because it is wrong: Choose $a =(N-(N-1)\epsilon, \epsilon, \ldots, \epsilon)$ and  $b =(\epsilon, \ldots, \epsilon, N-(N-1)\epsilon)$

Comment: Can it help to impose additional assumptions? I am specifically considering U-shapes parabolas $f$ which are evaluated at points $1,\dots,N$ and then normalized, such that $a_i = Nf(i) / \sum_{i=1}^N f(i)$.

Comment: i think using langranges identiy will be useful